# Automatic Login from 3rd-Party OneLogin Apps to My App

Tags: openid, onelogin

I’ve successfully implemented OneLogin OpenID login in my app using the flow described in the OneLogin API documentation : https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token

To summarise, I create a session token using the “Create Session Login Token” API and then post that token to the “Create Session” API. OneLogin adds a session cookie to the user’s browser, and everything works fine.

When a user logs into my app, they are automatically signed into other 3rd-party OneLogin apps as well, which is functioning correctly.

However, I’m facing an issue: If a user is signed into a 3rd-party OneLogin app, they are not automatically logged into my app. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

I’ve searched for documentation but haven’t found any specific guidance. What steps should I take to enable automatic login from 3rd-party OneLogin apps to my app?

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!